# ios google maps delegate events not firing in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, delegates

For some reason, I can't seem to get tap and longtap and all the other delegate events to work in my simulator.  I think I installed everything correctly because the map shows up on the screen, with a custom button click I can put a marker on the map, but it will not recognize the delegate events.  Am I doing something wrong???

mapviewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mapContainer;
- (IBAction)addmarker:(id)sender;
@end
```

mapviewcontroller.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController{
    GMSMapView *mapView;
}
@synthesize mapContainer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
//CLLocation *myLoc = mapView.myLocation;
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86 longitude:151.20 zoom:15];
mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mapContainer.frame.size.width, self.mapContainer.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
[self.mapContainer addSubview:mapView];
}

- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *) mapView didTapAtCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate{
NSLog(@"%f, %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
}

- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
NSLog(@"tapped");
}

- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
NSLog(@"tapped info");
}

- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didBeginDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
NSLog(@"dragged");
}

- (IBAction)addmarker:(id)sender {
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.title = @"hello";
marker.map = mapView;
}
@end
```

The only thing that works is the IBAction.  Also my location and compass buttons do not show up.  Any ideas of why it's not working?  I declared the delegates...

Comment: Apparently you were supposed to declare the delegate AFTER initializing mapView_...who knew...

Comment: It works... thanks a lot @denikov

Answer (score 1):

You need to set all properties after the object initialization.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86 longitude:151.20 zoom:15];
mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mapContainer.frame.size.width, self.mapContainer.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
[self.mapContainer addSubview:mapView];
}
```